# how to include a checkbox in backend of c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to include checkbox in backend of c#.

```
html.Append("<div ><input type = 'checkbox' id =" + j + " value = " + result + " /></ div >");
```

where html is a string builder.

I have already tried the above code but don't see results.

```
html.Append("<div ><input type = 'checkbox' id =" + j + " value = " + result + " /></ div >");
view.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
```

I want to include checkbox in the backend of c# code so that I get dynamic checkboxes in front end.

Comment: So whats the problem, whats the error, what is it returning, what dont you want, whats the question. Also this looks like a great case for interpolated strings

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the context of your question, I can only suggest from what I can see. I notice that you are not escaping your quotes to form valid html. Can you try this and see

```
html.Append("<div><input type=\"checkbox\" id =\"" + j + "\" value=\"" + result + "\" /></div>");
```